# How to get the value of option with attribute selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to get the value of the option which have the attribute "selected" to compare it to the current option selected.

```js
function onChangeOption(opt) {
  var update_value = opt.value;
  var selectedValue = '???'; // get selected attribute 
  if (update_value != selectedValue) {
    // Do some things    
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" onchange="onChangeOption(this)">
  <!-- I wanna got the content of option selected=selected-->
  <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `opt.value` will *always* be the selected option, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here

Comment: I know but how to get the default selected value?

Comment: @alexis store it on load, or just get the first option in the select if that will be the default

Comment: @alexis - What exactly is it that you want? I don't think it's a hard question, just confusing.

Comment: @user7393973 I want to get the content of the markup <option selected=selected> and compare this to the current option selected

Comment: @alexis - Is the `<option selected="selected">` always the first one or does it changes?

Comment: <option selected="selected"> is not always the first @user7393973

Comment: @alexis - What about the ammount of `<options>`? Is it always only 2?

Comment: It doesnt change @user7393973

Comment: @alexis - Check my answer, I think it's what you asked. Tell me if you need something to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think alexis actually wants something more like this:

```js
function onChangeOption(opt) {
  var update_value = opt.value;
  var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
  if (options[0].getAttribute("selected")=="selected") {
    var selectedValue = options[0].value;
  } else {
    var selectedValue = options[1].value;
  }
  if (update_value != selectedValue) {
    // If the selected option's value is not equal to the value of the option with the attribute "selected", then do... (this way, you can change the attribute to any of the options!)
    console.log(selectedValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" onchange="onChangeOption(this)">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment the result and if you need anything else. Glad to help.

Comment: JavaScript only and it actually checks for the attribute `selected`, unlike some of the other answers. It works just like you said you wanted, you can change the `selected` to any other `<option>` since the ammount of options [doesn't change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156335/how-to-get-the-value-of-option-with-attribute-selected#comment71478737_42156335).

Comment: It's something like this I was searching, I'll adapt it to my real context, thanks a lot

Comment: @alexis - If you do need to add more `<options>`, just add some more `if`s and `else`s or use a `case` instead. Also, try to always use pure JavaScript whenever you can and not jQuery because even tough it's less writting for the programmer, it's more reading for the computer. Good luck in your project!

Answer (score 2):

Just add `change` event listener.And get the selected value.You can achieve comparision between `selected` value and `changed` value by maintaining an array.Like below.

```js
values = []//creates an array

select = document.querySelector('#myselect');
values.unshift(select.value);
//console.log(values);
select.addEventListener('change',function(){
update_value = this.value;
console.log(this.value);
 if (update_value != values[0]) {
   // alert('Not matched');
console.log('Not matched');
  }
  else{
  //alert('Matched');
  console.log('Matched')
  }
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="myselect">
     <option selected="selected" value="1"> 1 </option> 
     <option value="2"> 2 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Then what's the attribute `selected` for? I have no ideia if that's what OP wants or not.

Comment: the selected value will be displayed on `change` event.The attribute `selected` is used for initially select a value.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// save initial selected value to a variable
var initSelected = $('.form-control option:selected').val();

$('select').on('change', function() {
  // check if the selected value is the same as the initial one was
  if(this.value == initSelected) {
    console.log('same values');
  } else {
    console.log('not same values');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always store previously selected values, if you want to access them somehow later on: [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/fykztqcL/).

**HTML:**

```
<select id="mySelect" class="form-control" onchange="onChangeOption(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<p>Previous: <span id="prev"></span></p>
<p>Current: <span id="curr"></span></p>
```

**JS:**

```
var selectElem = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var prev = document.getElementById("prev");
var curr = document.getElementById("curr");

var allEverSelected = [ selectElem.value ];

selectElem.addEventListener("change", function(evt){
  allEverSelected.push( this.value );
  prev.innerHTML = allEverSelected[allEverSelected.length - 2];
  curr.innerHTML = allEverSelected[allEverSelected.length - 1];
});
```

To access **default** value, just get the `<select>` value after DOM loads.
`selected` attribute on `<option>` tag exist only to make other than first `<option>` element inside `<select>` default option, i.e.:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option selected value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Above select's default value is 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the one what you want. Try it.

```js
function onChangeOption(opt) {
  var update_value = opt.value;
  console.log(update_value);
  var selectedValue;//  = '???'; // get selected attribute 
 // I think this is the one you want
 //If you want to select the HTML element,
  selectedValue=document.querySelector("option[value='"+update_value+"']");

  console.log(selectedValue);
//
  if (update_value != selectedValue) {
    // Do some things    
  }
}
//onChangeOption(document.querySelector('form'));
function start(){
  while(typeof document.querySelector('form')!=typeof {}){}
  onChangeOption(document.querySelector('.form-control'));
}
```

```html
<body onload="start()">
<select class="form-control" onchange="onChangeOption(this)">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
  <!-- I wanna got this -->
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select></body>
```